# PHP LOST SESSION

Tags: php, session, redirect

It's the first time I have that problem.

Basically, when I execute the login function, I create a session var which is passed to the index.php file.

The problem is that if I refresh the browser, or click to other menu items, I lost the session.

Here some code:

```
public function Login_Form()
{
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
        $this->login($_POST);
 ?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP-SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="form_login">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
</table>
</form>
 <?php
}

private function login($p)
{
    // OTTENGO VALORI PASSATI DAL LOGIN FORM
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($p['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($p['password']));
    // CONTROLLO CHE ESISTA L'UTENTE
    $control = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tareado.user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        while($x = mysql_fetch_array($control))
        {
            $id_utente = $x['iduser'];
            $_SESSION['idutente'] = $id_utente;
        }

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        //session_write_close();            
        header("Location: index.php"); // REDIRECT TO INDEX.PHP, NOW WE ARE IN index.php?a=log
        //exit();

    }
    else
        echo "Credenziali errate";
}
```

I put on the top of index.php SESSION_START(), but I always lose the session.

Which could be the problem? The redirect?

Comment: Have you checked if there are any errors? You might have to set error reporting to all and see if there are (or rather not) happening unexpected things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a session start in the page where it get's redirected from. You could also use firebug to debug if the session even starts under the Cookies tab. You should see something like PHPSESSID when you try to login. Not sure if this is your answer but im unable to posts comments yet.

Comment: Read the last line. Your answer is a comment anyway.

Comment: I read the last line. You are talking about index.php, this is the page you are redericting to right? Not the page you are redirecting from..

Comment: The redirect is from index.php?a=log to index.php, I put session_start() on the top of the index page, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Wouldn't it be handier just to start inmideatly with a session, and just add a person to that session. That way your session always excist and its just a matter of defining when you have to remove the user from the session so they aint linked anymore. That way you can shoot session values over without being logged in.